# repopulate child dropdow when parent dropdown changed

Tags: php, jquery, json, html-select

TL;DR

How to make jQuery request from parent dropdown ( using .change() ) to working url that outputs JSON and repopulate child dropdown.

END TL;DR

I'm using Laravel 5.1 so my code will be a bit Laravel specific but not much since this is beginner level jQuery problem.

I have two dropdowns. One is for categories (parent) and other is for subcategories (child).

My parent dropdown:

```
<div class="form-group">
    {!! Form::label('category_id', '*Categories') !!}
    {!! Form::select('category_id', $categories, null) !!}
</div>
```

which generates

```
<div>
    <label for="category_id">Categories</label>
    <select id="category_id" name="category_id">
        <option value="1">Category 1</option>
        <option value="2">Category 2</option>
        <option value="3">Category 3</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

My child dropdown:

```
<div sytle="display:none;">
    {!! Form::label('subcategory_id', 'Subcategory') !!}
    {!! Form::select('subcategory_id', [], null) !!}
</div>
```

which generates

```
<div sytle="display:none;">
    <label for="subcategory_id">Subcategories</label>
    <select id="subcategory_id" name="subcategory_id">
    </select>
</div>
```

I have defined route: `subcategoriesfordropdown/{i}` to which I send `i` and it gives me JSON with the children of parent category. For example if I use URL `subcategoriesfordropdown/2` I get:

```
{"3":"Subcategory 1 title","4":"Subcategory 2 title"}
```

Numbers in `""` are subcategories IDs. This is all working properly.

Now I want to repopulate child dropdown with these id/title pairs so that I get:

```
<div sytle="display:none;">
    <label for="subcategory_id">Subcategories</label>
    <select id="subcategory_id" name="subcategory_id">
        <option value="3">Subcategory 1 title</option>
        <option value="4">Subcategory 2 title</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

I made this jQuery script:

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#category_id").change(function (){
        var category = $(this).val();
        alert( "Category: " + category );
    });
});
</script>
```

And it pops an alert box with category ID as I change the parent dropdown values. However, instead of alert function I want it to run POST request (I believe POST is the right one here but GET is OK too) to get the JSON data and create options values from it. Also change the `display:none;` but that shouldn't be a problem.

I tried replacing `alert();` with:

```
$.post( "/subcategoriesfordropdown/" + category, , function( data ){
    alert( "Data: " + data );
});
```

to receive the data given by `subcategoriesfordropdown/{i}` but I'm failing here.

So here is my TODO list:

- run POST request
- get JSON data
- populate child dropdown with JSON data
- remove display:none; attribute

I hope I ain't missing something elese here. Thank you all in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're definitely on the right tracks.

The only issue I see with your `$.post` is the extra `,` after `category`. I'd also suggest using the "json" tag - it just prevents you have to use `json_decode` within the function.

To update the select box you can use Javascript along these lines.
(Untested, but theoretically correct barring typos)

```
$.post( "/subcategoriesfordropdown/" + category, function( data ){
     var $select = $('#subcategory_id');
     $select.empty();
     $.each(data, function(value, text){
          $select.append($("<option></option>")
              .attr("value", value).text(text));
     });
     $select.show();
}, "json");
```

Comment: Thanks, only change the `var $select = $('subcategory_id');` to `var $select = $('#subcategory_id');`. I really need to get better IDE than Geany... it's not that big of a problem when I do things I'm familiar with, but when the syntax is unknown i just lose too much time. Do you maybe know any simple way to debug JS?

Comment: I haven't really used any enough to make a solid recommendation, unfortunately.